# Prove an inequality with sizable exponents

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, exponential-function, fractions, number-comparison

### The Problem

Show $2^{100} + 3^{100} \lt 4^{100}$

### My Attempt

$$2^{100} + 3^{100} \lt 4^{100}$$

Rewriting $4^{100}$ as $2^{200}$

$$\implies 3^{100} \lt 2^{200} - 2^{100}$$

$$\implies 3^{100} \lt 2^{100}(2^{100} - 1)$$

As $2^{99} \lt 2^{100} - 1$, to prove our original statement it is sufficient to show $3^{100} \lt 2^{100}(2^{99})$

$$3^{100} \lt 2^{100}(2^{99})$$

$$\implies 3^{100} \lt 2^{199}$$

Making the power of 2 a nicer number

$$\implies 2(3^{100}) \lt 2^{200}$$

$$\implies 2(3^{100}) \lt 4^{100}$$

$$\implies 2 \lt \frac{4^{100}}{3^{100}}$$

$$\implies 2 \lt (\frac{4}{3})^{100}$$

I can show this by looking at smaller powers of the ratio $\frac{4}{3}$

$$(\frac{4}{3})^{3} = \frac{64}{27} \gt 2$$

$$\implies 2 \lt (\frac{4}{3})^{3} \lt (\frac{4}{3})^{100}$$

Thus the original inequality holds. QED

### Questions

Is this prove rigorous enough?

Have I made any assumptions that are non-trivial and should be shown?

**Is there a more elegant method?**

Comment: Replace all the "$\implies$" with "$\Leftarrow"$s.  You are trying to prove your result (stated in the first line) wit sufficient but not nesc. conditions.  So You don't know that any line is true, and no line implies the next.  But instead every line is implied *BY* the next line and the previous lines are true *IF* the final line is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may seem nitpicky but be it is *VERY* important that when you start the proof with

$2^{100} + 3^{100} < 4^{100}$ that you state that you do NOT know that to be true but that that is your desired result.

And it is important that you don't say $2^{100} + 3^{100} < 4^{100} \implies 3^{100} < 2^{200} - 2^{100}$.  That is claiming you are starting for a hypothesis (that you do not know) and are trying to conclude a result (that you do not want;  you want the *hypothesis*).

What you should say is something like:  " $2^{100} + 3^{100} < 4^{100}$ would be true if we could show $3^{100} < 2^{200} - 2^{100}$.

In other words, replace all $\implies$ with $\Leftarrow$ and .... presto, your proof works!

And it does.  There is no error (other than the implication misdirection).

However it'd be better if you used this as a rough draft and worked *forward* not backwards.

$2 < (\frac 43)^3 < (\frac 43)^{100}\implies.... \implies 2^{100} + 3^{100} < 4^{100}$.

Although... now I'm getting into style critique... working forward yields other emphases and ... reveals a faster solution:

$(\frac 43)^3= \frac {64}{27} > 2$.

So $2 < (\frac 43)^3 < (\frac 43)^{100}$.

So $2*3^{100} < 4^{100}$

So $3^{100} + 3^{100} < 4^{100}$.  As $1 < 2 <3$ we know $2^{100} < 3^{100}$.

So $2^{100} + 3^{100} < 3^{100} + 3^{100} <4^{100}$.

Answer (score 2):

Because $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{100}<\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{27}{64}\right)^{\frac{100}{3}}<\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$2^{100} + 3^{100} < 3^{100}+ 3^{100}=2\cdot 3^{100}\lt 4^{100}\iff 2<\left(\frac43\right)^{3}<\left(\frac43\right)^{100}$$

Comment: How do I show $log 2 + log 3 \lt log 4$?

Comment: $\log 2 + \log 3 = \log 2*3 = \log 6 > \log 4$. So that result is out and out wrong.  But $\log (2^{100} + 3^{100}) \ne \log(2^{100}) + \log (3^{100})$ so that is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

As written, your proof is **incorrect**. The problem is that you started off with the inequality you *want* to prove and manipulated it until you found a true statement. This is logically incorrect and invalidates the proof. It's the same as writing

$$0 = 1 \implies 6 = 7$$
by adding $6$ to both sides; but since the hypothesis is wrong, there is nothing we can conclude.

---

However, your steps are all reversible. So you can replace the forward implications with the reverse ones, and the idea works. But you've only done the scratchwork, not the proof.

Comment: I would prefer a straight forward proof where the OP starts with $2 < (\frac 43)^3 < (\frac 43)^{100} \implies 2*3^{100} < 4^{100} \implies.... \implies 2^{100} + 3^{100}$.  But *if* the op sprinkles in "It will be sufficient to prove that.."  and "such would be true if" and "this would be implied by" and "\Leftarrow" generously to what s/he does have in his/her direction, I would say s/he *has* done the proof, not just "scratchwork".  But you are correct that "would be sufficient" *MUST* replace the $\implies$ which as written *ARE* out and out wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For fun:

Show:

$ 2^{100} \lt 4^{100}  -3^{100}.$

Consider

$f(x)= x^{100}$, $x \gt 0,$  real.

MVT:

$\dfrac{f(4)-f(3)}{1} =f'(a)$,

where $3\lt a \lt 4$, i.e.

$4^{100} -3^{100} = 100(a)^{99} =(100/a)a^{100}.$

Hence :

$4^{100} -3^{100} = (100/a)a^{100} \gt (100/4)3^{100} =$

$(25)3^{100} \gt 2^{100}.$

Used: $f(x) =x^{100}$ is an increasing function.